# How to efficiently use a template as a variable in Flask?

Tags: html, templates, flask, jinja2

I am using flask to develop my website and i often have to use graph to display data, so I'd like to have a route that display a graph and then use it as a template. The way I found to do it is the following:

- Two html files : `tender.html` and  `template.html` with the first one used as the file to display to the user and the second one used as a template for graph that can be re-used in other routes

`template.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" integrity="sha512-UXumZrZNiOwnTcZSHLOfcTs0aos2MzBWHXOHOuB0J/R44QB0dwY5JgfbvljXcklVf65Gc4El6RjZ+lnwd2az2g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.2.1/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="sha512-klQv6lz2YR+MecyFYMFRuU2eAl8IPRo6zHnsc9n142TJuJHS8CG0ix4Oq9na9ceeg1u5EkBfZsFcV3U7J51iew==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="chart-container" style=""><canvas id="myChart-1"></canvas></div>
<div>div-test</div>
<script>  
    const dataset_1 = [{
        label: "Spread of ",
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        order : 3,
        pointRadius:0,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor:"blue",
        data: {{ data | safe }},
        yAxisID: 'y'
        },
    ];
    const data_1 = {
        labels: {{ label | safe }},
        datasets : dataset_1
    };
    const zoomOptions = {
        animations: false,
        tranistions: false,
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x',
            
        },
        zoom: {
            wheel: {
            enabled: true,
            },
            drag: {
            enabled: true,
            modifierKey: 'ctrl',
            },
            mode: 'x',
            onZoomComplete({chart}) {
            // This update is needed to display up to date zoom level in the title.
            // Without this, previous zoom level is displayed.
            // The reason is: title uses the same beforeUpdate hook, and is evaluated before zoom.
            chart.update('none');
            }
        }
        };
    const config_1 = {
    data: data_1,
    options: {
        animations:false,
        transitions:false,
        responsive: true,
        interaction: {
        },
        stacked: false,
        plugins: {
        zoom : zoomOptions,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: "bla bla"
        }
        },
        scales: {
        y: {
            type: 'linear',
            display: true,
            position: 'left',
            borderWidth : 0.001,
        },
        x: {
            display: true,
            grid :{
            display:false
            },
        },
        },
    },
    };
    const myChart_1 = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart-1'),config_1);
</script>
```

`tender.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% autoescape false %}
    {{template}}
{% endautoescape %}
 
</body>
</html>
```

- The route in my flask app that "join" the two files

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    template = render_template('template.html',data=[2,4,1,9,5,2],label=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
    return render_template('tender.html', template=template)
```

Obviously this solution is completely fine but i thought that render_template was meant to only be used with return, at the end of routes so i was wondering wether there was a more natural or prettier way to do the job. I was thinking there was as i have to use autoescape on my template variable to have my stuff rendered.

Thanks for your help already and I can clarify my point if it isn't clear enough !

Comment: Template inheritance is the standard method of reusing templates in this manner. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/

Comment: That's not really my idea. I don't want to have inheritance but i want to be able to use a standard graph template where i just give data and i get a html block representing my graph as a variable in python, just like i did